# Application failed to launch and is shutting down?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm learning how to switch layouts but i'm getting `unfortunately application has stopped` but i have no idea why?

I'm using an emulator nexus 4 im not sure if this may cause the problem or not.

code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: move `Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);` into onCreate method, after `setContentView`

Comment: @GeorgeBailey it worked! thanks!